# Pandas .pivot_table() reorder the index in chronological order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, seaborn

Im trying to create a pivot table out of the seaborn flights dataset. When I come to make a pivot table for a heat map the index column is ordered alphabetically when I want to order it chronologically from Jan to Dec. Does anyone know how to do this? I have deleted the values in the pivot table to make it look tidier when I copied and pasted from Jupyter notebooks.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

#Loading dataset
flights = sns.load_dataset('flights')

#Calling dataset
flights

year    month   passengers
0   1949    January 112
1   1949    February    118
2   1949    March   132
3   1949    April   129
4   1949    May 121
... ... ... ...
139 1960    August  606
140 1960    September   508
141 1960    October 461
142 1960    November    390
143 1960    December    432

flights.pivot_table(values='passengers',index='month',columns='year')

year 1949 1950 1951 1952 1953 1954 1955 1956 1957 1958 1959 1960
month                                               
April   Values.....
August  
December    
February    
January 
July    
June    
March   
May 
November    
October 
September
```

Comment: what pandas version are you on with `pd.__version__`. I don't have this issue on `1.1.3`.

Comment: ^^^ Edit: it appears the issue might be the version of seaborn (not pandas) that you are on from StupidWolf's answer. Try upgrading to the latest version of seaborn if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am on seaborn '0.10.1' and if you look at the data, it is categorical and sorted in the correct order:

```
flights.month.dtype

CategoricalDtype(categories=['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
                  'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November',
                  'December'],
                 ordered=False)
```

If you do pivot, it should be sorted correctly. Else you set it as a category:

```
flights['month'] = pd.Categorical(flights['month'], categories=flights.month.unique())
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be just reindex and provide the index list as follows:

Code :

```
import  calendar

month_names = [calendar.month_name[i] for i in range(1,13)]
# ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

newdf = df.reindex(month_names)
```